# MySQL connection pooling with embedded Jetty

Tags: connection-pooling, embedded-jetty

I have a working WebSocket server based on the current release of Jetty. It runs as an embedded server, mainly because I don't know anything about writing servlets and embedding Jetty seems to be one of the few well documented things with this server.

So it works well until now. Incoming requests are stored in a MySQL database. Since there can be very many of these requests I would like to use connection pooling so that I don't lose time when opening and closing connections each time. And that seems to be a problem since I cannot find any good documentation about connection pooling with embedded Jetty and MySQL. I guess it cannot be that hard but I'm missing the idea where to start.

Has anyone already implemented connection pooling with Jetty and can show me the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
I've implemented connection pooling using the C3P0 library. That seems to work fine. But since Jetty supports connection pooling to, I guess I should rather use that instead of some third party library.

Answer (score 2):

Jetty supports JDBC connection pooling, but you have to provide your pooling library, for example c3p0 or dbcp. See examples: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/DataSource+Examples .

So, in fact, based on your update you are already doing what you were going to. Congratulations!